# Running npx create-expo-module results in "Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1"

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx

I'm trying to create my own Expo module following the instructions in the [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/).

When I run the command `npx create-expo-module` and I fill out the information that it asks me for (name of npm package, module name, GitHub profile, etc.), it manages to do the first two steps of the module creation:

```
✔ Downloaded module template from npm
✔ Created the module from template files
```

But then it gives me this error in the 3rd step:

```
✖ Installing module dependencies
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:41:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at installDependencies (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\create-expo-module\build\packageManager.js:9:37)
    at C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\create-expo-module\build\create-expo-module.js:49:56
    at newStep (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\create-expo-module\build\utils.js:21:22)
    at Command.main (C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\62900f925a4b91dc\node_modules\create-expo-module\build\create-expo-module.js:48:31) {
  pid: 23924,
  output: [ '', '' ],
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '',
  status: 1,
  signal: null
}
```

I'm able to create new Expo projects with `expo init` without an issue and run them with `expo start`, so I don't know what the issue could be. My version of the Expo CLI is 6.0.6 and npm is 8.19.2.

Comment: could you try doing `npm install` manually on the folder created and show the log?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue with `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

1. Just run npx create-expo-module and get the error, delete
   node_modules and lock file
2. Install "rsync" package with Cygwin installation -
   https://www.cygwin.com/install.html
3. Add path to your env vars, my path was "C:\cygwin64\bin"
4. Git bash at your project root folder and yarn install (Dont forget
   to restart your bash if it was opened during adding path to env
   vars)

You are ready to go and this is only windows related problem, you will be ok on mac os if you use yarn

If you dont use yarn on both os, you will get an error. (Internal Error: ...@workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; run "yarn install" to update the lockfile)

Hope this,helps.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that fixed this issue for me on Mac (For Non Mac see issue two - perhaps it's not possible to test IOS app on Windows but issue one should be enough for you to code without the example app ios you can just use example app android) :

Please note that there are two steps that can fail this fixed both for me:

1. Failure at the "Installing module dependencies" step
2. Failure at the "Installing dependencies in the example app" step

The example app is created automatically by the expo module bootstrapper

**Steps I took that fixed issue 1:**

1. `rm /Users/mac/package.json`
2. `rm /Users/mac/yarn.lock`
3. `cd ~`
4. `yarn set version classic`
5. `cd Documents`
6. `yarn create expo-module my-module` (don't use npx ... not sure why this is how I made it work)

**Steps I took that fixed issue 2:**

1. Install XCode (The XCode CLI tool kit is sadly not enough on its own)
2. Open XCode > Preferences > Location if no path is shown under Command Line tools just reselect the path